# Changing JLabels between classes

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, constructor

My first post, so forgive any incorrect etiquette. I'm currently doing my year end project for school and I need a bit of help. I am making a GUI java app in Netbeans. I have two classes. One is a class that controls a timer, the other is a class that is a scoreboard screen. I need to update the scoreboard timerLabel with the time that is being counted down in the timerClass. Its quite messy as there is another timer label in the Timer class *which does update*. My problem is that I cannot get timerLabel in MatchScreen() to update. Here is my code :

Timer Class

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TimerClass extends JFrame {

    Timer timer;
    JLabel promptLabel, timerLabel;
    int counter;
    JTextField tf;
    JButton button;
    MatchScreen call = null;

    public TimerClass() {
        call = new MatchScreen();
        setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 4, 7, 7));
        promptLabel = new JLabel(""
                + "Enter number of seconds for the timer", 
                SwingConstants.CENTER);
        add(promptLabel);
        tf = new JTextField(5);
        add(tf);
        button = new JButton("Start");
        add(button);
        timerLabel = new JLabel("waiting...", 
                SwingConstants.CENTER);
        add(timerLabel);

        event e = new event();
        button.addActionListener(e);
        System.out.println("Button pressed");
    }

    public class event implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Action performed");
            int count = (int) (Double.parseDouble(tf.getText()));
            timerLabel.setText("Time left: " + count);
            call.setTimerLabel(count);
            System.out.println("Passed count to tc");
            TimeClass tc = new TimeClass(count);
            timer = new Timer(1000, tc);
            System.out.println("Timer.start");
            timer.start();
            //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
        }

        /*public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
        }*/
    }

    public class TimeClass implements ActionListener {

        int counter;

        public TimeClass(int counter) {
            this.counter = counter;
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            counter--;
            if (counter >= 1) {
                call.setTimerLabel(counter);
            } else {
                timerLabel.setText("END");
                timer.stop();
                Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        TimerClass gui = new TimerClass();
        gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        gui.setSize(250, 150);
        gui.setTitle("Time Setup");
        gui.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

And now the ScoreBoard Screen

```
public class MatchScreen extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    int redScore = 0, blueScore = 0, blueCat1 = 0,
            blueCat2 = 0, redCat1 = 0, redCat2 = 0, winner = 0;

    public MatchScreen() {
        initComponents();
    }

    //Determine Winner of the match
    public int getWinner() {
        if (redScore > blueScore) {
            winner = 1;
        } else {
            winner = 2;
        }
        return winner;
    }

    public void setTimerLabel(int a) {
        int time = a;
        while (time >= 1) {
            timerLabel.setText("" + time);
        }
        if (time < 1) {
            timerLabel.setText("End");
        }
    }

    private void jButton13ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        //Creates an object of the timerClass
        TimerClass gui = new TimerClass();
        gui.setSize(300, 175);
        gui.setTitle("Time Setup");
        gui.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Some code that I felt is irrelevant was left out from the MatchScreen().

Many thanks

Comment: You forgot to mention what your problem is

Comment: Also, if this is schoolwork, tag it homework so people providing answers can answer accordingly.

Comment: Ah, thank for the quick reply. I cannot get the JLabel to updated from another class. I tried passing the value through to the MatchScreen class but that doesn't work for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Managed to solve the general problem. I put all the code into one class. Not ideal, but it works :/ Anyway, deadlines are looming.

Sincere thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have a while loop in the `setTimerLabel` method, which I don't think you intended to put there. Also, you take the parameter `a` and assign it to `time` and then never use `a` again, why not just rename your parameter to `time` and bypass that additional variable?

**EDIT**

Sorry, I forgot to explain what I'm seeing :P If you say `call.setTimerLabel(10)` then you hit that while loop (`while(time >= 1`) which is essentially running `while(10 >= 1)` which is an infinite loop. Your program is never leaving the method `setTimerLabel` the first time you call it with a `value >= 1`.

Comment: @user1030290 You pass it fine, it's just the `int time=a` that's not necessary, I'd go with just using `a` for all your tests or changing the method declaration to `public void setTimerLabel(int time)` either way, the latter is more readable. I don't know why you'd be instructed to waste an assignment like that. What about the loop issue, have you changed that at all?

Comment: Aha, I understand about the extra variable. Its the way we were taught to pass variables in school. :D 

I have changed the while loop to an if. `if(time>1){ 
                timerLabel.setText(""+time);
                System.out.println(time);}`
I added println statements which all display correctly. i.e the if and else statements in my code are run as they should. The passed value can also be displayed from within the method via println statements. So this leaves me with the possibility that my JLabel does not want to update. Any ideas as to why this would happen ?

Comment: @user1030290 I can provide more details in a few hours, I don't have access to a Java IDE or Compiler right now.

Comment: The only real conclusion that I can come to is that the timerLabel refuses to update. I still have no way of getting it to change.